# Проблемы с работой скрипта маски телефона maskedinput в Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor, mask

Скрипт в форме на странице Elementor работает, а в форме во всплывающем окне Elementor - нет. Кто-то может подсказать причину, и как с этим бороться?

Comment: "как с этим бороться" -- например дебажить. Вообще по количеству деталей которые Вы привели, трудно сделать хоть какие-то выводы, кроме того что у Вас Elementor, две форми и в модалке не работает маска.

Comment: Ответ так же глубок, как и мой вопрос, очевидно. А какие еще детали нужны? Подскажите, - я добавлю. Консоль не ругается. Форму прямо на странице я тестовую делал. Она работает правильно. Она мне не нужна, и я ее удалил.

Comment: А какого ответа Вы ожидаете?) Какой ответ Вы бы сами дали кому-то в такой ситуации? Ну например могли бы дать немного больше деталей о том, откуда вообще в Вашем плагине/теме берется этот скрипт, где и как Вы его инитите? Вероятно что скрипт инитится до того как появляется форма в модальном окне или может быть еще куча других причин в зависимости от того что это за форма и как она стоится.

Comment: Ответ ниже. Я надеялся, что кто-то это решение нашел до меня. А так потерял лишние 2 часа. И что значит откуда берется? Вы ничего об этом скрипте не знаете, и что-то пишите? Я знаю о нем лет 5, и всегда с успехом применял. Вот столкнулся с использованием в попапе, и застрял.

Comment: Вместо минуса за вопрос можно поставить плюсик за ответ. )))

Comment: Конкретно я не минусовал, если что) Ну а так, Вы же никакого кода в вопросе не приводили и не понятно что искать.

Answer (score 1):

Решение вопроса предложил Михаил Кобзарев: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/masked-input-for-elementor/
Когда мы инициализируем скрипт маски, нужно изменить скрипт инициализации.
Стандартный:

```js
jQuery(
  function( $ ) {
    $( 'input[type="tel"]' ).mask(
      '+7-(999)-999-9999',
      {
        placeholder: ' '
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Этот код работает в простой форме.

А для нормальной работы маски в форме в попапе нужен такой:

```js
jQuery(
  function( $ ) {
    $( document ).on(
      'elementor/popup/show',
      function ( event, id, instance ) {
        $( 'input[type="tel"]' ).mask(
          '+7-(999)-999-9999',
          {
            placeholder: ' '
          }
        );
      }
    );    
  }
);
```

Но и этот вариант не идеален.
Я вместо " 9 " употребил " * ", и все заработало.